# New Spring MVC project with Spring Data JPA or Hibernate?

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

We are currently starting to use Spring MVC for a new project, and we were wondering what is the best technology to use  to connect to our databases? Spring Data JPA or Hibernate?

PS: This is our first project with any of these technologies.

Comment: I was unable to go online during this weekend, that's the only reason I hadn't accepted your answer yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Data JPA OR Hibernate? JPA is an interface if you want, Hibernate is the implementation. You specify the Hibernate to be your JPA provider.

But when you get a hold of that I would encourage you to use Spring Data JPA. First it's pretty darn easy, less code, etc. I've used it my last two projects and I loved it. You can add the Query DSL for type safe queries and your life is going to be even funner.

This is actually a very good place to start:

[Spring Data JPA Tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/)